# json api response data fields

Tags: javascript, json, response

how can you properly use data fields in javascript? I dont know how to drill down to them... for example i can use data, but i can't use the TaskName that is underneath data. Please help thank you.

If I parse the response like this: `var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);`

how do i get to a field like TaskName??
Usually I would try something like `data.TaskName === "003021919913";`
but that is not working.

```
{
  "Data": {
    "QRCode_ID": 168,
    "Repairer_ID": null,
    "AssignedToEmployee_ID": null,
    "TaskName": "003021919913",
    "DueDate": "2015-07-02T00:12:53.597",
    "DueDateTimeSpan": 1959471956224,
    "TaskStatus_ID": 1,
    "Description": "due 6/30, 5:00",
    "TaskUrgency_ID": null,
    "TaskType_ID": null,
    "DueDateDisplay": "2015-07-02 00:12",.......
      }
  },
  "Messages": [
    "success"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Udated answer:

You should be able to access "TaskName" via `data.Data.TaskName`.

In this case your library is storing your JSON object into a var `data`. this variable becomes a reference to the object, inside of the object it has a property `Data` which holds the property that you want to use, which you can access w/ dot syntax.

Now, something else that might hook you up. In your test, you want to make sure your testing TaskName against the String value of 003021919913 in this case, if you're testing it against the number, you'll need to do something like:

```
var taskNameTest = parseInt(data.Data.TaskName);
assert(taskNameTest).equal(003021919913); //not sure what assertion library you're using.
```

hopefully that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am calling an API with a tool called Postman and am trying to make a test for it with a tool called Jetpacks. Basically I call the API then the test parses the response body with this line: var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

from there, I need to make a test that verifies one of data's fields i.e. taskname is equal to a certain string in this case 003021919913. so that is where im running into problems because if i write data.TaskName = "003021919913" it says it can't find it, because presumably im not drilling down one level because i dont know how to...

Comment: i just looked at the updated question -- you should be abl eto acccess it with data.Data.TaskName